# nested forms and one to one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a one-to-one relationship between user and goal. I want to build a form that shows the goal of a user. The problem is that my code only works when the user already has a goal defined. The text field is not rendered when no goal is present.

```
<%= user_builder.fields_for :goal do |goal_builder| %>
   <%= goal_builder.text_field :goal %>
<% end %>
```

Does Rails provide an easy way to do this?

Comment: If goal has just a single field why not just store it in the user model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :goal
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :goal
  after_initialize do
    self.goal ||= self.build_goal()
  end
end
```

Comment: thx for the reply. When I use the Goal.new it will always create a new goal object also when a goal was already defined. Can I somehow only create the new goal conditionally?

Comment: in the after_initialize block, it seems you could use : self.goal ||= self.build_goal()

Comment: BTW I think I would even prefer `self.buid_goal unless self.goal`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

In the view, as you had:

```
<%= user_builder.fields_for :goal do |goal_builder| %>
  <%= goal_builder.text_field :goal %>
<% end %>
```

In the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :goal # or belongs_to, depending on how you set up your tables
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :goal
end
```

See the documentation on [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), and the [form_for method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) for more information.