# Rails 3.2 : Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that has amenities with a 1:1 relationship:

```
  class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

      attr_accessible :address1, :address2, :bath, :bedroom, :city, :description, :neighborhood, :sleeps, :sqft, :state_id, :title, :zip, :images_attributes, :amenity_attributes

      has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true

      has_one :amenity
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :amenity, :allow_destroy => true
   end
```

And Amenities table:

```
class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :air_conditioning, :balcony

  belongs_to :listing

end
```

Lastly, my view:

```
   <%= simple_nested_form_for (@listing), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>
          <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.input :title %>
            <%= f.input :sleeps %>
            <%= f.input :bath %>
            <%= f.input :bedroom %>
            <%= f.input :sqft %>
            <%= f.input :neighborhood %>
            <%= f.input :address1 %>
            <%= f.input :address2 %>
            <%= f.input :city %>
            <%= f.input :state_id %>
            <%= f.input :zip %>
            <%= f.input :description %>
          </div>

            <!-- amenities -->
            <%= f.fields_for :amenities do |a| %>
                <div class="amenities">
                    <label><%= a.check_box :smoking %> Smoking Allowed</label>
                </div>
            <% end %>
                <!-- end amenities -->
    <!-- Submit button -->
<% end %>
```

When I hit submit I get the error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: amenities
```

Any idea what's up here? It won't submit even though I allow :amenities_attributes and accepts_nested tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :amenity
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :amenity
  after_initialize do
    self.amenity ||= self.build_amenity()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a has_one association so amenities should not be plural.

change

```
 <%= f.fields_for :amenity do |a| %>
```

EDIT

```
 <%= f.fields_for :amenity do |a| %>
            <div class="amenities">
                 <%= a.label :smoking, 'Smoking Allowed' %>
                <%= a.check_box :smoking %>
            </div>
         <% end %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
     <% end %>
```

Also, checkout this documentation for a one to one association, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Interesting, that change removed every in between the commented out sections   
`<!-- amenities -->
            <%= f.fields_for :amenities do |a| %>
                <div class="amenities">
                    <label><%= a.check_box :smoking %> Smoking Allowed</label>
                </div>
            <% end %>
<!-- end amenities -->` 
from the html source.

Comment: Can you take out all the comments, especially the one with 'end' in it... Do you mean it no longer displayed the nested checkbox?

Comment: Correct, it does not display the nested checkbox

Comment: check my edited answer and make sure you have no comments in your form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871796/nested-forms-and-one-to-one-relationship fixed it, thanks!